# IBus client for GNU Emacs: Installed, but how do I start it?

Tags: emacs, ibus

Having recently moved to Linux/Ubuntu, I'm looking for a good editor, and **GNU Emacs** seems to fit the bill.

One thing I want from a text editor is the ability to handle Unicode Input Method Editors in a "normal way", across the board. For Ubuntu, the "normal way" is via **IBus**.
However, emacs does not support IBus "off the shelf".

I found a launchpad project: [IBus client for GNU Emacs](https://launchpad.net/ibus.el): **ibus-el**.

I've installed ibus-el and set it up as per the `Customize` section of [this emacswiki IBusMode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IBusMode#toc1) page. I included the suggested "toggle" keybinding: `;; Use s-SPC to toggle input status`

It seems to have installed okay, but I have no idea how to invoke IBus and switch IMEs.

**s-SPC** doesn't fire up the IBus language panel... I'm stuck :( ...so close, yet so far....

Here are the startup *messages*

```
Loading 00debian-vars...
No /etc/mailname. Reverting to default...
Loading 00debian-vars...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...done
Loading debian-ispell...done
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50festival.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50gtk-doc-tools.el (source)...done
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50ibus-el.el (source)...done
IBus: Xlib.protocol.request.QueryExtension
IBus: Agent successfully started for display ":0.0"
```

Comment: which emacs version did you installed: emacs22, emacs23 or emacs-snapshot? you are running the GTK version or terminal version?

Comment: The verion I am using is (from the Help--About): GNU Emacs 23.1.1 (i486-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.20.0) of 2010-03-30 on rothera, modified by Debian .... (straight out of the Ubuntu Repository)

Comment: Could you post the relevant section of your .emacs file, ie the section with the code you added from the emacs wiki?

Comment: @Steven D, It's okay now. I managed to get it working (although it does has a minor(?) issue with Devanagari script, where it repeats the last character of a word when I press space after the word (temporary workaround: Left+Right+Space) .. I hope to eventually sort it out somehow).... The main problem seemed to be a mismatch between the way Emacs (ibus-el) expected to switch IBus on/off, and how IBus (native) expected it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a good look at the situation again today (more that 2 months later)... as I've mentioned in the comment above (and repeated here)..

I managed to get it working (although it does has a minor(?) issue with Devanagari script, where it repeats the last character of a word when I press space after the word (temporary workaround: Left+Right+Space) .. I hope to eventually sort it out somehow).... The main problem seemed to be a mismatch between the way Emacs (ibus-el) expected to switch IBus on/off, and how IBus (native) expected it.

There may have been some other issue(s) involved in getting Emace **ibus-el** running, but the nett result is that *it does work* :)